# Why custom actuator endpoint created using @RestControllerEndpoint are not mapped to /cloudfoundryapplication in pcf?

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-boot-actuator, pcf

I have created a custom actuator endpoint in spring boot using @RestControllerEndpoint and I am able to access it under actuator/, but same is not available under /cloudfoundryapplication when I deploy to pcf and make management.cloudfoundry.enabled: true

All other endpoint are visible under /cloudfoundryapplication

I tried creating using @Endpoint and its working but In that I am not able to pass custom pojo in requestbody so have to use @RestcontrollerEndpoint approach.